# How do I get all the values in a listbox when looping through them?

Tags: asp.net, listbox, asp.net-2.0, listbox-control

I'm currently trying to move through all the values added to a listbox by the user, however, I want to retrieve the actual value of each item in the listbox and not the text.

I've gotten so far with the code below, but that only gets the text and not the value.

```
For Each item In SelectedStoresLB.Items
            Dim tCompany As Integer = CInt(Left(item.ToString, 1))
            Dim tStore As String = Right(item.ToString, 3)
            Dim tReason As String = ReasonTxt.Text
            insertSQL = "INSERT INTO [CommsDownLog] ([DimCompanyID],[PervasiveStoreNumber],[DownReason]) VALUES (" & tCompany & ", '" & tStore & "', '" & tReason & "')"
            Dim insertRow = New SqlCommand(insertSQL, objConn)
            Try
                objConn.Open()
                insertRow.ExecuteNonQuery()
                objConn.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                Response.Write(ex)
            End Try
        Next
```

How would I go about getting the value for each item in the collection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`item` is a `ListItem` object - rather than call `ToString` on it, you should use the `Text` and `Value` properties to get the info you need.

Answer (score 1):

Using VB 2010, note to get the actual values of the items in the listbox you need to use the "Content" property of the ListBoxItem object.  Eg:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To lstSortUs.Items.Count - 1
    sAllItems &= lstSortUs.Items(i).Content & ";"
Next
sAllItems = Left(sAllItems, Len(sAllItems) - 1)
arrAllItems = sAllItems.Split(";")
System.Array.Sort(arrAllItems)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
item.Value
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Hmmm... are you sure that this is not a correct answer? Since `item.Value` would indeed get the value...

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful when iterating over a ListBox because you may end up modifying the underlying collection. By using foreach as you are, you are utilizing the underlying enumerator. I recommend you modify your iterator to the following (C# example):

```
foreach (ListItem li in listbox.Items.ToArray())
{
    if (li.Selected)
    {
        Controltest2.Remove(li.Value);
    }
}
```

By doing this, you are modify the Array's collection and not the list's collection. This assumes `LINQ` to object and you may need to call `Cast<t>` to make it work in some cases.

The reason for this is below:

> The foreach statement repeats a group
>   of embedded statements for each
>   element in an array or an object
>   collection. The foreach statement is
>   used to iterate through the collection
>   to get the desired information, **but
>   should not be used to change the
>   contents of the collection to avoid
>   unpredictable side effects**

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6%28VS.80%29.aspx)

To get the text you want after iterating, use `.Value` instead of `.Text`. Of course, there are other ways to iterate such as going in reverse with an indexed for loop, but that's another topic :)